# Dynamically Adding Data Roles (Collapsible data role)

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I have a table with a table data-role that i would like to add a collapsible data role to. However i would have to add this dynamically through JQuery Mobile code.

```
 $('#tabledataroleid').data('role','collapsible-set');
 $('#tabledataroleid').data('role','collapsible');
```

Is there something off with my code? ^

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening? Asking a more specific question than is there something wrong with my code will get you more help faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [jQuery .attr() method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to add attributes to an element. Try this:

```
$('#tabledataroleid').attr('role','collapsible-set');
$('#tabledataroleid').attr('role','collapsible');
```